# Shutdown when laptop lid closed

Tags: 12.04, power-management, shutdown

I want my laptop to shutdown when I close the laptop lid. 
But in the power settings I can only choose between:

- Suspend
- Do nothing
- <strike>Hibernate</strike> (Disabled)

Is there any way to configure it with more options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the action to other values, such as shutdown, blank or interactive, by using `gconf-editor`.

[image]

First, install `dconf-tools`, then launch gconf-editor from the Dash.

Navigate to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`.

The two items of interest are `lid-close-as-action` and `lid-close-battery-action`. Click the existing value to change it.

To quickly change the action to shutdown when the lid is closed, open a terminal window and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action shutdown

gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action shutdown
```