# Shut down by closing NoteBook

Tags: shutdown, lid

As a matter of fact Im quite new to Ubuntu and spent the last 2 hours finding a possibility/adjustment to "Shut Down" my Laptop when i close it ??

Maybe someone can help me with my little problem.

Greetings

Comment: Two hours?
Less than a minute on google:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/265800/shutdown-when-laptop-lid-closed

Comment: Shouldn't be soooo mean, but it is easy.